# How do you determine the hybridisation state of a coordinate complex?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, hybridization

If an exercise asks for the hybridisation state of a coordinate complex (ion in solution) consisting of a central cobalt atom surrounded by $\ce{NH_3}$ ligands, and neither coordination number or complex ion is given, how do you decide which configuration will occur?

The answer is that in a solution this will form a $\ce{[Co(NH_3)_6]^{3+}}$ complex ion. I know that this means the hybridisation is $\mathrm{d^2sp^3}$ but can't figure out how to get there since cobalt is found in different oxidation states.

Answer (score 8):

Again, [I feel](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/43022) [a bit](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/44749) [like a](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/51775) [broken record](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/62226). **You should not use hybridisation to describe transition metal complexes.**

Instead, you should discuss transition metal complexes using molecular orbital theory; a simplified version of it such as the crystal field theory may also suffice for simple complexes. Below, I have attached the orbital scheme of an octahedral coordination complex of a random transition metal not including π effects.

[image: orbital scheme octahedral complex]
**Figure 1:** molecular orbital scheme of an octahedral $\ce{[ML6]}$ complex. Originally taken from [Professor Klüfers’ coordination chemistry course’s web scriptum (in German)](http://www.cup.lmu.de/ac/kluefers/homepage/L_kc.html).

Forcing hybridisation onto this system is very bad and very wrong; look at the huge energy differences between the 3d, 4s and 4p orbitals. Hybridisation would also lead us to assume six equal bonds, which is not the case: the six $\ce{M\bond{->}L}$ bonds transform as $\mathrm{a_{1g} + e_g + t_{1u}}$ which leads to three different energies. And finally, hybridisation is not able to explain crystal field split, and why $\mathrm{e_g}$ — the orbitals that should take part in hybridisation and thus form bonds — are raised in energy (they are $\mathrm{e_g^*}$ in MO terms).

In most cases, coordination complexes would default to octahedral or derived. The main catch case is low-spin $\mathrm{d^8}$ in which case square-planar should be assumed. This is relatively independent of the type and number of ligands and most exceptions are due to sterics. Thus, octahedral complex is a safe first guess. Note that the only difference between two complexes of the same metal and ligands but with different metal oxidation states is typically whether a Jahn-Teller distortion is relevant and how strong it is.

Comment: You'd perhaps be surprised to know that in Indian curriculum we are supposed to use hybridization *even in CFT*. Like in hexaaquacobalt(III), after splitting into t2g and eg, cobalt's six electrons fill the t2g and eg is empty. We are then supposed to use the two empty d orbitals of eg, plus 4s and 4p to give it a d2sp3 hybridization, which are then filled with electrons from aqua ligands. Sounds pretty horrible to you, I expect ;)

Comment: I wonder why it's still like this @TRC